# setState in onFunctionCall not changing the values

Tags: flutter, widget, parent-child, bottom-sheet

I'm showing bottom sheet and by default I have given bool closeBottomSheet true to its **isDismissible & enableDrag** properties and on hitting api in bottom sheet when I click upload button I'm passing function on which I'm changing the closeBottomSheet value from true to false in setState.
I'm printing the values and its changing properly but don't know why its not setting these value these properties  **isDismissible & enableDrag**

Here is my code

```
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    elevation: 10,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    isDismissible: closeBottomSheet,
                    enableDrag: closeBottomSheet,
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => BottomSheet(onCompletion: (value){
                      print("val $value");
                      setInnerState(() {
                        closeSheet = value;
                      });

                      print("cbs $closeBottomSheet");
                    }
                      )).then((value) {
                  getAllPlaylists(0, 5);
                });
```

Button in bottomSheet

```
   RectangularButton(
                  title: "Create",
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if(tvPlayListModel.playlistName == '' || tvPlayListModel.playlistName.length  <= 2) {
                       UtilService().getDangerMsg("Minimum length of playlist name is 3 characters.", context);
                    }
                    else if ( _image == null){
                      UtilService().getDangerMsg("Please pick an image first.", context);
                    }
                    else{

                      setState(() {
                        widget.onCompletion.call(false);
                        showSpinner = true;

                      });

                      createPlayList();
                    }

                  },
                ),
```

I want when user click upload button in bottom sheet he shouldn't be able to drag down or dismiss bottom sheet until upload is finished.
I'm printing values and they are changing correctly